# Integral of Liouville-Von Neumann

Tags: quantum-mechanics, integration, calculus, density-operator, time-evolution

When integrating the Liouville-Von Neumann equation:

$$
\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} = -\frac{i}{\hbar}[H, \rho]
$$

you get:

$$
\rho(t) = \rho(0)-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int^{t}_0d\tau[H(\tau),\rho(\tau)]
$$

where does the $\rho(0)$ term come from?

Comment: It comes from the [fundamental theorem of calculus:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)$$\int_a^b \frac{df}{dt} \, dt = f(b) - f(a).$$

Answer (score 4):

It's a differential equation. Integrating both sides over time leaves you with a $\int \mathrm{d}\rho = \rho(t) - \rho(0)$. You need an initial condition to pick out a specific solution to the differential equation.

Comment: This is just [the fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).